# The Torah and the Jews

Tags: quran, hadith, jews, judaism, torah

I was talking to a Jewish friend of mine, topic came to whether the Torah the Jews have now is the one actually sent to Moses. She said that the Rabbis told her that the Torah they have right now is indeed the original Torah. I said that would be impossible; if nothing else, Allah would not send the Qur'an while the original Torah is still around. Of course what I said is hypothesis. I have also quoted the Qur'an:

> Do you (faithful believers) desire the unbelievers to believe in your
> religion. There was a group among them (Jewish rabbis) who would hear
> the word of God [Torah] and understand it. Then they would purposely
> misinterpret it. **—Qur'an 2:75**
>
> Some Jews take certain words out of context and by twisting their
> tongues to make a jest out of the true religion, say, "We heard and
> (in our hearts ) disobeyed. (Muhammad) ra`ina (be kind to us) but they
> intend thereby (the meaning in their own language): "Listen! May God
> turn you deaf." They should have said, "We heard and obeyed.
> (Muhammad) listen and consider our question." This would have been
> better for them and more righteous. God has condemned them for their
> disbelief, thus, no one, except a few among them, will have faith.
> **—Qur'an 4:46**
>
> O Messenger! Do not be grieved about the people who run back to
> disbelief. They only say that they believe but, in fact, they have no
> faith in their hearts. Some Jews knowingly listen to lies and accept
> the lies which come from others, [Jews], who have no relation with you
> and who distort certain words of the Bible and say to the people,
> "Accept only those words which are the same as what We have told you.
> If you do not, then beware!" You can not help those whom God wants to
> try. God does not want to cleanse the hearts of such people. They lead
> a disgraceful life in this world and in the life hereafter they will
> suffer a great torment. **—Qur'an 5:41**
>
> And [mention, O Muhammad], when Moses said to his people, "O my
> people, why do you harm me while you certainly know that I am the
> messenger of Allah to you?" And when they deviated, Allah caused their
> hearts to deviate. And Allah does not guide the defiantly disobedient
> people. • And [mention] when Jesus, the son of Mary, said, "O children
> of Israel, indeed I am the messenger of Allah to you confirming what
> came before me of the Torah and bringing good tidings of a messenger
> to come after me, whose name is Ahmad." But when he came to them with
> clear evidences, they said, "This is obvious magic." —**Qur'an 61:6-7**
>
> It is He who has sent His Messenger with guidance and the true
> religion to make it prevail over all other religions. God is a
> sufficient witness to this truth. **—Qur'an 48:28**
>
> And whoever seeks a religion other than Islam, it will never be
> accepted of him, and in the Hereafter he will be one of the losers.
> **Qur'an —3:85**

And also few hadith:

> By Him in Whose hand is the life of Muhammad, he who amongst the
> community of Jews or Christians hears about me, but does not affirm
> his belief in that with which I have been sent and dies in this state
> (of disbelief), he shall be but one of the denizens of Hell-Fire.
> [Sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/293)
>
> Ibn Abbas said, "Why do you ask the people of the scripture about
> anything while your Book (Qur'an) which has been revealed to Allah's
> Messenger is newer and the latest? You read it pure, undistorted and
> unchanged, and Allah has told you that the people of the scripture
> (Jews and Christians) changed their scripture and distorted it, and
> wrote the scripture with their own hands and said, "It is from Allah,"
> to sell it for a little gain. Does not the knowledge which has come to
> you prevent you from asking them about anything? No, by Allah, we have
> never seen any man from them asking you regarding what has been
> revealed to you!" [Sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/96/90)

However, the portions I quoted from the Qur'an do not unequivocally assert that the original Torah does not exist, nor does it assert that the Jews must become Muslims.

Are there other ayath in the Qur'an that would shed light on this matter?

Comment: You should elaborate how these aren't unequivocal. Note that there are different madhabs on tahreef of the scriptures. One is that the text has been distorted, another is that only the interpretation has been distorted and there there are others, the first is the correct one according to the majority. The Quranic basis for tahreef includes various verses like [5:13-14](https://legacy.quran.com/5/13-14), [2:79](https://quran.com/2/79) etc. and also the ones that you have quoted.

Comment: Even if we assume the Torah is the same certainly the rules concluded or applied from it are not. This can certainly be concluded from the qur'an (you've quoted some of these references).

Comment: @Medi1saif♦  Can you give examples?

Answer (score 2):

There is another avenue of proving that the original Torah doesn't exist. Simply, showing where Allah corrects the current Bible and Gospel.

In the Bible, Eve was tempted by the serpent and ate the fruit:

> 4 “You will not certainly die,” the serpent said to the woman. 5 “For God knows that when you eat from it your eyes will be opened, and you will be like God, knowing good and evil.”
>
> 6 When the woman saw that the fruit of the tree was good for food and pleasing to the eye, and also desirable for gaining wisdom, she took some and ate it. She also gave some to her husband, who was with her, and he ate it. ([Genesis 3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%202%3A4-3%3A24&version=NIV))

Whereas Allah pretty explicitly mentions Adam (AS) as the one Shaitan whispered to:

> Then Satan whispered to him; he said, "O Adam, shall I direct you to the tree of eternity and possession that will not deteriorate?" (20:120)

In the Bible, God rested after the third day:

> 2 By the seventh day God had finished the work he had been doing; so on the seventh day he rested from all his work. 3 Then God blessed the seventh day and made it holy, because on it he rested from all the work of creating that he had done. ([Genesis 2](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%202&version=NIV))

Allah says (quite pointedly towards this passage):

> And We did certainly create the heavens and earth and what is between them in six days, and there touched Us no weariness. (50:38)

In the Bible, Moses sees the fire while he was tending the flock of his father-in-law:

> 3 Now Moses was tending the flock of Jethro his father-in-law, the priest of Midian, and he led the flock to the far side of the wilderness and came to Horeb, the mountain of God. 2 There the angel of the Lord appeared to him in flames of fire from within a bush. Moses saw that though the bush was on fire it did not burn up. 3 So Moses thought, “I will go over and see this strange sight—why the bush does not burn up.”
>
> 4 When the Lord saw that he had gone over to look, God called to him from within the bush, “Moses! Moses!” ([Exodus 3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%203&version=NIV))

On the other hand, Allah clearly says he was with his family when he saw the fire, and he had already completed the term of his father-in-law:

> And when Moses had completed the term and was traveling with his family, he perceived from the direction of the mount a fire. He said to his family, "Stay here; indeed, I have perceived a fire. Perhaps I will bring you from there [some] information or burning wood from the fire that you may warm yourselves."
>
> But when he came to it, he was called from the right side of the valley in a blessed spot - from the tree, "O Moses, indeed I am Allah, Lord of the worlds." (28:29-30)

In all four Gospels, Jesus is killed on the cross.

However, Allah says:

> And they did not kill him, nor did they crucify him; but [another] was made to resemble him to them. And indeed, those who differ over it are in doubt about it. They have no knowledge of it except the following of assumption. And they did not kill him, for certain. (4:157)

And Jesus (AS) says:

> "And peace is on me the day I was born and the day I will die and the day I am raised alive." (19:33)

I don't think death on the cross can be construed as "peaceful" in any meaningful way.

There are countless examples like this, and these corrections are intended by Allah. Allah says:

> And We have revealed to you, [O Muhammad], the Book in truth, confirming that which preceded it of the Scripture **and as a criterion over it**. (5:48)

And one of the quite explicit verses about the Torah and Injil having been superseded by the Quran is what Allah says here:

> Those who follow the Messenger, the unlettered prophet, whom they find written in what they have of the Torah and the Gospel, **who enjoins upon them what is right and forbids them what is wrong and makes lawful for them the good things and prohibits for them the evil and relieves them of their burden and the shackles which were upon them.**
>
> So they who have believed in him, honored him, supported him and followed the light which was sent down with him - **it is those who will be the successful.** (7:157)

The "shackles which were upon them" refers to the restrictive laws they have in their books which forbid them from a lot of things that are halal in Islam.

In addition, Allah mentions "making lawful" and "forbidding" as the function of Muhammad (SAW) over those scriptures. Meaning, something they might consider permissible, he may forbid (like alcohol). And something they might consider forbidden, he may allow (like camel meat for Jews).

Allah clearly tells us how the People of the Book can be "successful." They need to believe in and follow this Prophet superseding the laws they used to have in the Torah and Injeel.

Answer (score 1):

Here are words of Allah in Torah in Hebrew bible.
Word of God Elohim is derived from name of Allah אלח in ancient hebrew lexicon
Compressive  hebrew etymological dictionary state that etmyos means "that which is true sense"  is the only true word in Hebrew. Means truth can be found using etymology. So there is no God no elohim but Allah
That is why we say There is no God but "Allah".
https://youtu.be/ezMkJgllzvo
Becoz early  Christian  scholar and jewish sources proved that true word is Allah in Torah as a creator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quote that might help:

> "But for breaking their covenant We condemned them and hardened their hearts. **They distorted the words of the Scripture and neglected a portion of what they had been commanded to uphold**. You ˹O Prophet˺ will always find deceit on their part, except for a few. But pardon them and bear with them. Indeed, Allah loves the good-doers." (Quran: 5/13)

And Allah knows best.

Answer (score -3):

In my personal study of the Quran about this particular issue I have found several significant insights from the teachings of both the Quran and Hadiths, which I have enumerated in an article on a facebook page: https://www.facebook.com/MuslimMisunderstandings/posts/1745445425738447

Here I am giving just the summary of my findings:

(1) Quran does mention that the Tawrat, Zaboor and Injeel are Allah’s words/books

Quran - Surah 5:43-47; 21:105

(2) Quran declares Allah’s words cannot be changed

Quran - Surah 6:34; 10:64;

(3) As per the Quran Tawrat, Zaboor and Injeel were with Jews and Christians

Quran - Surah 7:157; 2:113; 5:43; 10:94;

(4) Quran teaches that Tawraat, Zaboor and Injeel are a guide and light

Quran - Surah 5:44-46

(5) Quran instructs that the Tawraat, Zaboor and Injeel must be followed

Quran - Surah 5:43; 5:68

(6) According to the Quran Tawraat, Zaboor and Injeel should not be treated differently than the Quran

Quran - Surah 2:136; 4:136;

(7) Quran claims that it came to confirm the Tawraat, Zaboor and Injeel. Notice, it doesn't claim to replace them or correct them.

Quran - Surah 2:40-41; 2:89,91, 101; 3:50; 4:47; 61:6

(8) Quran warns that Tawraat, Zaboor and Injeel should not be vilified

Quran - Surah 40:70-71;

(9) Quran on the corruption of the previous books i.e. Tavraat, Zaboor, and Injeel

The Quran charges specifically some Jews, not Christians nor even all Jews everywhere, that they have changed the meaning of their Scriptures (Tahrif al-Mana) or hid the portions of the Scriptures or wrote scriptures of their own. But it never makes a blanket statement that all of the previous books got textually corrupted (Tahrif al-Nass) all over the world by Jews and Christians. The following are the important verses from the Quran that talk about the so-called corruption of the previous books:

Quran - Surah 2:75,79,159,174; 3:78,187; 4:46; 5:13-15; 6:91; 7:162;

None of the above verses imply the following:

- Textual corruption
- Corruption of all the previous Scriptures
- Corruption to the previous Scriptures all over the world

(10) Finally, the Hadiths on the corruption of the Bible

There are more than 30,000 so called authentic hadiths. Out of all these only two hadiths report negatively about the previous books. The negative comments in those two hadiths were made not by the Islamic prophet Muhammad but others.  Even those others did not tell that all the previous Scriptures everywhere got corrupted and therefore should not be accepted as God’s word.  Here are those two hadiths:

i.  Bukhari Volume 9, Book 92, Number 461

ii. Bukhari Volume 9, Book 93, Number 614

Contrary to the misinterpretations of the above hadiths the following hadiths tell us how the Islamic prophet Muhammad treated and viewed the previous Scriptures according to the first Muslims:

i) Sunan Abu Dawud Book 38, Number 4434

Narrated Abdullah Ibn Umar:  A group of Jews came and invited the Apostle of Allah (peace_be_upon_him) to Quff. So he visited them in their school. They said: AbulQasim, one of our men has committed fornication with a woman; so pronounce judgment upon them. They placed a cushion for the Apostle of Allah (peace_be_upon_him) who sat on it and said: Bring the Torah. It was then brought. He then withdrew the cushion from beneath him and placed the Torah on it saying: I believed in thee and in Him Who revealed thee. He then said: Bring me one who is learned among you. Then a young man was brought. The transmitter then mentioned the rest of the tradition of stoning similar to the one transmitted by Malik from Nafi'.

ii)  Sunan Abu Dawud Book 38, Number 4431

iii) Sahih Bukhari Volume 4, Book 56, Number 829

The Bible Christians read today comes from the manuscript copies that predate Islam. Christians have been honestly admitting the fact that there are many ancient copies with variant readings. But to say every single ancient copy is surely corrupted and differs with the original is not only a presumptuous declaration but also an uninformed judgment against the divine Scriptures that came with divine protection. It is a too small a thing for the Almighty God to keep at least one ancient copy of his word with absolute perfection like the originals while the scholarly research affirms that there are more than one such copies in extant. All praise and glory to God who spoke through prophets, gave his word through inspired writers and assured us that ‘The word of the Lord abides forever’ (The Bible: Isaiah 40:8; 1Peter 1:25).